# A way to find the size of an iPhone app store category?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, itunes-store

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to determine the number of apps in an iTunes app store category?

In particular, I'm interested in the games categories since there are several of them and I'm only allowed to be in 2.  Need to pick my choices wisely...

Seems like there might be a website somewhere that has this data?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: From the FAQ: "Matters that are unique to the programming profession"   There are lots of questions about the app store and itunes connect on here.  They even have their own question categories.

Comment: Those are generally more for questions of the type "Can I still get into the app store using method X?". Someone could want to know the number of apps in a category for any number of reasons. I just meant to warn you that it isn't likely for you to get very many good answers, if any at all.

Comment: I knew it was a little off topic, but SO is still probably the best place to ask.  I'm sure other dev's will find this useful at some point and at the end of the day isn't the idea to build a useful resource of information for developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this data manually in iTunes on your mac.  iTunes > App Store > Games, then to get to a specific category, scroll down, and on the lower right will be 'More Games'.  Choose a category from here, e.g. 'Strategy'.  Then scroll down till you see 'All Strategy iPhone Apps'.  Look right and you'll see 1-24 of 4125.

I haven't looked myself, but you may also be able to retrieve this data through the iTunes App Store [Affiliate](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation.html) API.